# How to match nested function invocations (bracket pairs) using a regular expression (recursive?)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression (**) that will match an unknown number of nested functions.
So

```
expression
function(expression)
function(function(expression))
function(function(function(expression)))
etc.
```

will all match successfully. But for instance if I add an extra closing bracket at the end it wouldn't be included in the match.

(**) Please don't answer that this would be easier to do by parsing (and counting brackets) rather than using a regular expression - after scratching my head for a while I know that already!

Comment: This is not a regular language, so there exists no RE that can recognize it.

Comment: This would be easier to do by parsing (and counting brackets) rather than using a regular expression

Comment: @larsmans, while you're correct that a formal regular expression cannot represent this, there are indeed regex dialects that allow for some recursion support, such as PCRE or the .NET engine with its balancing groups. Either way, a proper parser should be used here, and the regex only for tokenization.

Comment: @SteveChambers: can you tell us *why* you'd want an RE for this problem if a simple stack-based parser can solve it?

Comment: @larsmans Thanks for the q. This is being done in Javascript and have already gone way too far down the route of regular expressions to change that. If it's not possible using regular expressions (which seems the case based on the answers and negging) I'll just have to go with an inferior regex that doesn't really match what it's supposed to...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm looking for a regular expression (**) that will match an unknown number of nested functions.

Some regex implementations support recursive matching (Perl, PHP, .NET), but JavaScript does not. So, the answer to your question is: no, that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks - guess I was kind of expecting this (but hoping there'd be a solution).

Answer (score 6):

This isn't recursive, but it does the trick.

#### PRECONDITIONS:

- Function names are alpha-numeric/underscore with possible leading white space.
- Function names do not start with a number.
- Expressions have no parentheses in them.
- There is only one expression nested within the functions.

#### CODE:

```
var target = "function(function(function(expression)))";
var pattern = /\s*([a-zA-Z_]\w*[(](\s*[a-zA-Z_]\w*[(]|[^()]+[)]|[)])+[)])/;
var matches = target.match(pattern);
var target= matches[1];
```

#### REGULAR EXPRESSION DISSECTION:

```
\s*             // 0+ white space characters
(               // Capture group for what you want
  [a-zA-Z_]     //   1 letter/underscore
  \w*           //   0+ word characters (alpha-numeric/underscore)
  [(]           //   left parenthesis
  (             //   PIECES:
    \s*         //     0+ white space characters
    [a-zA-Z_]   //     1 letter/underscore
    \w*         //     0+ word characters (alpha-numeric/underscore)
    [(]         //     left parenthesis
   |            //   OR
    [^()]+      //     1+ non-parenthesis characters
    [)]         //     right parenthesis
   |            //   OR
    [)]         //     right parenthesis
  )+            //   1+ of these PIECES
  [)]           //   right parenthesis
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time with this. I especially like the format you've used for documenting the regular expression - makes it very clear. I've actually finished this now and ended up using a long regular expression similar to this that could handle three levels of nesting. (If you're interested can see it in the source of this webpage: http://sic.azurewebsites.net).) Was forced to do this since as Bart Kiers pointed out in the accepted answer, Javascript unfortunately does not support recursive matching in regular expressions.

Comment: No problem, sir. And although this is not a recursive regex, is this not a better answer than "this is not possible"?

Comment: I take the point but the answer was awarded before you posted yours and I'm reluctant to change it as to be fair Bart's answer does accurately answer the q ("unknown number of nested functions" ..."no, that is not possible"). Yours does provide a helpful alternative though so thanks for that.

Comment: You asked for a regex that gives you the parameter inside of an unknown number of nested functions. That's what I gave you, therefore it IS possible, making Bart wrong.

Comment: Think there may have been some confusion here. The regex was supposed to match the whole set of nested function invocations up to the last applicable bracket (but no more brackets if they exist) rather than the expression inside.

Comment: I updated it to include the whole set of nested function invocations. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting as per Bart Kiers's answer that some regex engines (excluding Javascript) have extended features to provide recursive matching - but such a feature shouldn't be considered to be a regular expression as per the formal definition.