# internally recursive regular expression java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following sql queries I'd like to be able to group in one regular expression:

`CREATE INDEX blah_idx ON blah (id ASC)`

`CREATE INDEX blah2_idx ON blah2 (foo ASC, id DEC)`

I'd like to be able to use a java regex to group these so that I get:

`blah_idx, blah, id, ASC`

`blah2_idx, blah2, foo, ASC, id, DEC`

I can get the first with `CREATE INDEX (\\\w+) ON (\\\w+) \\((\w+) (\w+) \\)` but I'd like to be able to also group the second but I can't see to define `\\((\w+) (\w+) \\)` to match repeatedly.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left out some parentheses for readability. And spaces can be `\\s+` or `*`.

```
"CREATE INDEX \\w+ ON \\w+ \\((\\w+ (ASC|DESC)(, \\w+ (ASC|DEC))*))\\)"
                              1     2        23       4       43 21
```

Nested groups `( ( ) )` are allowed and are numbered from left to right. For retrieval see the javadoc.

```
    final String[] sqls = {
        "CREATE INDEX blah_idx ON blah (id ASC)",
        "CREATE INDEX blah2_idx ON blah2 (foo ASC, id DEC)",
        "CREATE INDEX blah2_idx ON blah2 (foo ASC, id DEC, name ASC)",
    };

    final Pattern createIndexPattern = Pattern.compile(
      "CREATE INDEX (\\w+) ON (\\w+) \\(((\\w+) (ASC|DESC)(, (\\w+) (ASC|DEC))*)\\)");
    for (String sql : sqls) {
        System.out.println("SQL: " + sql);
        Matcher m = createIndexPattern.matcher(sql);
        if (!m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("No match!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Match!");
            int groupCount = m.groupCount();
            for (int groupI = 1; groupI <= groupCount; ++groupI) {
                System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n", groupI, m.group(groupI));
            }
            String[] fieldsWithOrdering = m.group(3).split(",\\s*");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fieldsWithOrdering));
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh that's very cool. I think I can work with this, since I know I have at most 3 sets of that `foo ASC,` section. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of a question I once asked:

[How to match nested function invocations (bracket pairs) using a regular expression (recursive?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584124/recursive-regular-expression-matching)

Not possible in most Regexp languages including Java unfortunately.

Comment: could have posted this as a comment I suppose.

Comment: ah bummer... I guess I'll just match the outer, and then match the stuff inside the parens individually?

Comment: Usually have to resort to doing that kind of thing with regexes - at least it keeps it simpler for those reading your code.

Comment: @tophersmith116, or do it properly and parse it instead. @ Steve, most popular regex flavors support recursion (Perl/PCRE/etc), or similarly powerful constructs (balancing groups in .NET).