# Regex to match external block of brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have found some regex to match textblocks between brackets. However, what if I have some String with nested brackets and I only want the most external part of it.

eg. `"foo bar [first [second] [third]] asdf ]]]]"`

I would like to be able to match the text between the first opening bracket and it's closing bracket, leaving everything inside intact.

Result would be: `"[first [second] [third]]"`

Comment: It isn't possible in all language, what language do you use?

Comment: If recursion is supported: [**`\[(?:[^][]*|(?R))*\]`**](https://regex101.com/r/7heTQT/1/)

Comment: I use Java, if it wasn't supported, I would have to go for another approach... :)

Comment: Looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584124/how-to-match-nested-function-invocations-bracket-pairs-using-a-regular-express maybe the regex is the wrong approach?

Comment: [See the Java demo](https://ideone.com/hh6IBL), it now extracts multiple nested brackets. I also updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207892/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you for your answer. I was lookig for some "lazy" way where I could use existing code as a base. However, I ended up not parsing the string, but finding a way of getting the stuff I needed from Metadata since I was about to parse a String before having sent it through the network. Reason was that integration between different products is not always easy, but as I said, I found a way to pass the extra data in a Java Datastructure reliably...

Answer (score 2):

The classical recursion problem (if recursion is supported):

```
\[(?:[^][]*|(?R))*\]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7heTQT/1/).